# Date Format not working in IOS

Tags: ios, date, uidatepicker, target-action

I have date picker to select date and display it on a label. I'm trying a format of `yyyy-MM-dd`. But when I select any date the label does not show the date which I have selected from date picker.

How can I show this format `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Here is my code:

```
datepicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datepicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
datepicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[datepicker setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];

UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 216 - 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate)];
UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneBtn,space,nil]];

[_DOB setInputView: datepicker];

_DOB.inputAccessoryView =toolBar;


-(void)ShowSelectedDate {
    NSDateFormatter *fromatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [fromatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    self.DOB.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fromatter stringFromDate:datepicker.date]];
    [_DOB resignFirstResponder];
}
```

My date picker looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems like your method `ShowSelectedDate` is not invoked. Try to add a breakpoint inside your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an action method for intercepting the `UIControlEventValueChanged` of the date picker. Usually this is placed in the view controller class which manages the date picker:

```
-(IBAction)dateChanged:(UIDatePicker * )inPicker {
     // applying inPicker.date to your label
}
```

Add the action method to your picker as follows:

```
datepicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datepicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Where `self` is the view controller, which implements `dateChanged:`. You can also use your `ShowSelectedDate`method for that:

```
[datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Note: Since `ShowSelectedDate` takes no parameters there is no colon at the end in `@selector`.

You can also pass the date picker as parameter to `ShowSelectedDate`:

```
-(void)ShowSelectedDate:(UIDatePicker * )datepicker {
    NSDateFormatter *fromatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [fromatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    self.DOB.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fromatter stringFromDate:datepicker.date]];
    [_DOB resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Then you should apply the action with:

```
[datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Note the additional colon, because the method has now a parameter.

Comment: i didn't get what to do and what about my code? @macmoonshine

Comment: I have edited my post. Try modify your code according to the last two code blocks.